# Wavy effect over an image background with css

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

I want to make that wave effect over a parallax background image.
So far I have the parallax effect and full-width (over parent container width).

```
section.parallax {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    left: 50%;
    background-image: url(../images/parallax.jpg); // this image
    height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What can I do to have that wave effect on the image top and bottom with CSS? Is it possible?

Comment: You could create the wave as a second image, and apply it as a second background image, stretched to fit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea using SVG and multiple background. Simply adjust the `path` of the SVG to fit your needs:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="500" ><path d="M0 48 C30 60 38 40 64 48 L64 64 L0 64 Z"  fill="white" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" stroke-width="5"/></svg>') bottom,  
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="500" ><path d="M0 10 C30 20 38 2  64 10 L64 0  L0 0 Z"  fill="white" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" stroke-width="5"/></svg>') top, 
   url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

[image: CSS wavy shape]

Comment: How do you get the path? Is there a shortlink?

Comment: @A.Meshu I use this online tool to create it : http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M8%2048%20L56%2048%20L32%2012%20Z ... simply need to append the path on the link `d= ...` to edit it